# Side by Side Videos with faster frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been able to combine two videos into one single video with a side by side overlay and I have been able to increase the framerate for a movie but I cannot figure out how to do both.  I have tried the following.

```
ffmpeg -i gp1.mp4 -i gp2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.077*(PTS-STARTPTS),    pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=0.077*(PTS-STARTPTS)[fg]; [bg][fg]overlay=W-w-10:0:shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 19 output2.avi
```

My problem is that the output2.avi has all the frames sped up it plays fine but at the end of the compressed time it plays the last frame for what would be the duration of the non sped up version.

normal sped up video takes 20 mins of play back and gives 3 min in the output file.

side by side give 3 mins of sped video then 17 min of the last frame in output file.

```
 C:\Users\scottt\Videos\R103>ffmpeg -i GOPR0004.MP4 -i GP010004.MP4 -filter_compl
ex "[0:v]setpts=0.077*(PTS-STARTPTS), pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=0.077*(PTS-ST
ARTPTS)[fg]; [bg][fg]overlay=W-w-10:0:shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:
v libx264 -crf 19  output2.avi
ffmpeg version N-63146-g09cd228 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 14 2014 22:09:22 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-
libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libope
njpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsox
r --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab -
-enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
--enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-
libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 83.100 / 52. 83.100
  libavcodec     55. 61.101 / 55. 61.101
  libavformat    55. 37.102 / 55. 37.102
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR0004.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:32:32
  Duration: 00:19:53.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15120 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709
), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14985 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94
 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:32:32
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 15:31:36:03
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
7 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:32:32
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 15:31:36:03
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:32:32
      timecode        : 15:31:36:03
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GP010004.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:52:27
  Duration: 00:19:53.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15119 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709
), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14983 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94
 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:52:27
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 15:51:28:27
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
7 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:52:27
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 15:51:28:27
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:52:27
      timecode        : 15:51:28:27
[swscaler @ 0000000002a95fe0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did se
t range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000000052429e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did se
t range correctly
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] profile High, level 4.0
Output #0, avi, to 'output2.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    ISFT            : Lavf55.37.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 2560x720 [S
AR 1:1 DAR 32:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, s
tereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-15 15:32:32
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 15:31:36:03
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setpts (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> setpts (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:01.34 bitrate=  59.5kbits/s
frame=    7 fps=7.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=  30.0kbits/s
frame=   10 fps=6.6 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate=  20.2kbits/s
frame=   13 fps=6.5 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:05.30 bitrate=  15.1kbits/s
frame=   16 fps=6.4 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:06.62 bitrate=  12.1kbits/s
frame=   19 fps=6.3 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=  10.0kbits/s
frame=   22 fps=6.3 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:09.31 bitrate=   8.6kbits/s
frame=   25 fps=6.2 q=0.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:10.65 bitrate=  15.7kbits/s
frame=   28 fps=6.2 q=0.0 size=      41kB time=00:00:11.95 bitrate=  28.2kbits/s
frame=   31 fps=6.2 q=0.0 size=      62kB time=00:00:13.27 bitrate=  38.4kbits/s
frame=   34 fps=6.2 q=0.0 size=      84kB time=00:00:14.61 bitrate=  46.9kbits/s
frame=   37 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     105kB time=00:00:15.93 bitrate=  53.8kbits/s
frame=   40 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     126kB time=00:00:17.25 bitrate=  59.7kbits/s
frame=   43 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     146kB time=00:00:18.50 bitrate=  64.5kbits/s
frame=   46 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     166kB time=00:00:19.75 bitrate=  68.7kbits/s
frame=   49 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     186kB time=00:00:21.02 bitrate=  72.4kbits/s
frame=   52 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     205kB time=00:00:22.24 bitrate=  75.6kbits/s
frame=   55 fps=6.1 q=0.0 size=     224kB time=00:00:23.42 bitrate=  78.4kbits/s
frame=   57 fps=6.0 q=25.0 size=     420kB time=00:00:24.55 bitrate= 140.2kbits/
frame=   60 fps=6.0 q=25.0 size=     570kB time=00:00:25.77 bitrate= 181.2kbits/
frame=   63 fps=6.0 q=25.0 size=     679kB time=00:00:26.97 bitrate= 206.2kbits/
frame=   66 fps=6.0 q=25.0 size=     782kB time=00:00:28.22 bitrate= 226.9kbits/
frame=   68 fps=5.9 q=25.0 size=     871kB time=00:00:29.42 bitrate= 242.4kbits/
frame=   71 fps=5.9 q=25.0 size=    1009kB time=00:00:30.60 bitrate= 270.1kbits/
frame=   74 fps=5.9 q=25.0 size=    1111kB time=00:00:31.80 bitrate= 286.3kbits/
frame=   77 fps=5.9 q=25.0 size=    1212kB time=00:00:33.02 bitrate= 300.7kbits/
frame=   79 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1296kB time=00:00:34.20 bitrate= 310.5kbits/
frame=   82 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1398kB time=00:00:35.37 bitrate= 323.7kbits/
frame=   85 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1494kB time=00:00:36.57 bitrate= 334.5kbits/
frame=   88 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1593kB time=00:00:37.80 bitrate= 345.3kbits/
frame=   90 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1675kB time=00:00:38.90 bitrate= 352.6kbits/
frame=   93 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1770kB time=00:00:40.08 bitrate= 361.8kbits/
frame=   96 fps=5.8 q=25.0 size=    1871kB time=00:00:41.25 bitrate= 371.5kbits/
frame=   98 fps=5.7 q=25.0 size=    1919kB time=00:00:42.43 bitrate= 370.4kbits/
frame=  101 fps=5.7 q=25.0 size=    2014kB time=00:00:43.63 bitrate= 378.1kbits/
frame=  104 fps=5.7 q=25.0 size=    2109kB time=00:00:44.83 bitrate= 385.5kbits/
frame=  104 fps=5.1 q=25.0 size=    2109kB time=00:00:44.83 bitrate= 385.5kbits/
frame=  107 fps=5.1 q=25.0 size=    2200kB time=00:00:45.98 bitrate= 392.0kbits/
frame=  109 fps=5.1 q=25.0 size=    2283kB time=00:00:47.20 bitrate= 396.2kbits/
frame=  112 fps=5.1 q=25.0 size=    2377kB time=00:00:48.45 bitrate= 401.8kbits/
frame=  115 fps=5.2 q=25.0 size=    2466kB time=00:00:49.58 bitrate= 407.5kbits/
frame=  115 fps=4.5 q=25.0 size=    2467kB time=00:00:49.60 bitrate= 407.3kbits/
frame=  118 fps=4.5 q=25.0 size=    2555kB time=00:00:50.76 bitrate= 412.3kbits/
frame=  120 fps=4.5 q=25.0 size=    2599kB time=00:00:51.93 bitrate= 409.9kbits/
frame=  123 fps=4.5 q=25.0 size=    2687kB time=00:00:53.18 bitrate= 413.9kbits/
frame=  126 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    2775kB time=00:00:54.43 bitrate= 417.6kbits/
frame=  129 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    2864kB time=00:00:55.58 bitrate= 422.1kbits/
frame=  132 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    2949kB time=00:00:56.78 bitrate= 425.4kbits/
frame=  134 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    2997kB time=00:00:58.03 bitrate= 423.1kbits/
frame=  137 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    3087kB time=00:00:59.18 bitrate= 427.3kbits/
frame=  140 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    3180kB time=00:01:00.38 bitrate= 431.4kbits/
frame=  143 fps=4.7 q=25.0 size=    3268kB time=00:01:01.58 bitrate= 434.7kbits/
frame=  145 fps=4.7 q=25.0 size=    3354kB time=00:01:02.76 bitrate= 437.7kbits/
frame=  147 fps=4.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5009kB time=00:01:03.52 bitrate= 645.9kbits
/s dup=0 drop=1748
video:3941kB audio:993kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxin
g overhead: 1.527102%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] frame I:1     Avg QP:19.46  size:182228
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] frame P:56    Avg QP:19.48  size: 45589
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] frame B:90    Avg QP:21.55  size: 14448
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] consecutive B-frames:  1.4% 35.4% 46.9% 16.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] mb I  I16..4: 11.8% 55.4% 32.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  2.1%  0.4%  P16..4: 42.8% 17.4
% 15.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:21.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.6%  0.1%  B16..8: 37.8%  3.7
%  0.8%  direct: 2.9%  skip:54.0%  L0:45.0% L1:51.7% BI: 3.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] 8x8 transform intra:66.7% inter:58.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 76.2% 74.7% 41.5% inter: 2
1.5% 22.6% 2.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 18% 26% 32%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 14% 33%  5% 10%
 6% 10%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 18% 20%  6% 10%
 6%  9%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 21% 15%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] ref P L0: 49.4% 10.2% 27.2% 13.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] ref B L0: 57.6% 35.7%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] ref B L1: 87.7% 12.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002bfe620] kb/s:6581.96
    Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem
I was not increasing the playback speed of the audio.  by removing the -map 0:a command I get the overlayed video sped up to the correct time but without audio.  If I wanted to have audio I would have casdade atempo commands until I achieve a matching playback speed as the video as the max it will go up is 2.0 for one step